# ON CONFLICT в Postgresql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

отправляются 2 значения в базу

и если такие значения уже существует то пропустить а если null то перезаписать

```
например 
отправить в базу (null, 'm2151') но в базе уже есть (5421, 'm2151') то пропустить
------------
отправить в базу (5421, 'm2151') но в базе уже есть (5421, null) то null обновить и записать 'm2151'
```

можно ли это сделать с помощью правил или SQL

и первая и вторая колонка имеют уникальный индекс

если одна из колонок уже есть в базе и его значение не равно null то пропустить
если одна из колонок уже есть в базе и его значение равно null то перезаписать

как реализовать эти правила

в SQL ноль

Comment: На MySQL точно можно. синтаксис примерно такой:
`ODKU value1=IF(ISNULL(VALUES(value1)),value1,VALUES(value1))`
Чтоб стало понятней `value1` - хранит старое значение, а `VALUES(value1)` - новое, которое вы пытаетесь вставить через `Insert`

Comment: `null` в `sql` не конфликтует.

Comment: Есть одна проблема, что делать если сначала мы вставили в таблицу значения (5421, null) и (null, 'm2151') и тут мы пытаемся вставить запись (5421, 'm2151'). По вашей логике мы должны обновить значения в обоих записях, но это приведет к нарушению уникального ключа...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша структура и правила обновления несут массу скрытых проблем. Возможны разнообразные конфликты, по каждому из вариантов которых надо принять определенные правила поведения и отразить их в запросе.

Самая простая ситуация, когда в БД уже были вставлены 2 записи, которые при приходе данных должны объединиться в одну. Например у вас в таблице уже есть записи `(5421, null)` и `(null, 'm2151')`. И тут приходит связка `(5421, 'm2151')`. Очевидно, что в БД должна остаться только одна запись точно такая же как новая "добавляемая". Значит одну из существующих записей надо удалить, а вторую обновить.

Более сложная ситуация, в БД есть 2 записи `(5421, null)` и `(1111, 'm2151')`) а нам надо вставить запись `(5421, 'm2151')`. Я затрудняюсь сказать, что именно должно произойти, тут решать вам. Возможно надо удалить запись `(5421, null)` и более никаких записей не обновлять. Или изменить 1111 на 5421.

Кроме этого есть проблема с самим `on conflict` в postgresql. Ему необходимо указать при нарушении какого именно запрета производить update. На сколько мне удалось выяснить, способа задать условие срабатывающее при нарушении одного из двух правил невозможно.

Ввиду всего вышеперечисленного запрос получается довольно не тривиальным:

```
with new(a,b) as (values(3, 'x567')), -- тут "вставляемые" значения
 for_del as(select test.a, test.b from test, new -- Выборка записи, которую надо удалить
             where ((test.a=new.a::int and test.b is null)
                 or (test.b=new.b::varchar and test.a is null))
               and (select count(1) from test where a=new.a::int or b=new.b::varchar)=2
             limit 1
 ),
 del as(delete from test using for_del -- Удаляем запись, если необходимо
         where (test.a=for_del.a or (test.a is null and for_del.a is null))
           and (test.b=for_del.b or (test.b is null and for_del.b is null))
        returning * -- Если что то удалено, будет возвращена удаленная строка
 ),
 ins as(insert into test(a,b)
        select a::int, b::varchar
          from new
         where not exists(select 1 from del) -- Добавляем запись только если ничего не удаляли
            on conflict do nothing
         returning * -- insert вернет запись только если она действительно вставлена
 )
update test
   set a=coalesce(test.a, new.a::int), b=coalesce(test.b, new.b::varchar)
  from new
 where not exists(select 1 from ins) -- Обновляем запись если она не вставлена
```

Запрос составлен исходя из следующей структуры БД:

```
create table test(a int, b varchar(10));
create unique index test_a on test(a);
create unique index test_b on test(b);
```